# COLLADA 3D content creation, how?

Tags: ios, macos, scenekit

I am looking for a tool to start with simple 3d objects for Scene Kit. I know there are a lot professional tools out there, but just buying blind a program to try a bit how things work would be wasted money.

How do I create 3D content for a Scene Kit scene, beyond using the builtin geometry and geometry creation tools within Scene Kit?

Comment: Tool recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** [Blender](http://www.blender.org).

**Long answer:** Blender, because it's free and as good as any other 3D app (they are unfortunately all quite bad) but take this to the Apple Developer forums if you'd like more info, as this question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. The way you're thinking about this is also not appropriate; no app is a "Colada editor". That would be like saying Photoshop is a JPEG editor.

The [Unity forum](http://forum.unity3d.com) is also a great place to hear a bunch of opinions; unlike any of Apple's tools other than Logic or perhaps Final Cut, it has a wide-ranging user base of technically-minded artists from whom to gather opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Use Polygon Modelling.

COLLADA content is created in 3D modelling programs. There are three main ways of creating 3D content: polygon modelling, clay/brush style push/pull modelling of highly complex meshes, and what's most commonly known as NURBS modelling.

Polygon modelling involves creating shapes by articulating and adding primitive pieces of geometry to primitive pieces of geometry and progressively building up complex shapes in this manner. It has several massive advantages for game engine content creation that have seen it become (far and away) the most popular manner of making content for game engines.

Namely:

- Strict and absolute control of the amount and type of geometry (performance)
- Strict and absolute seam and inter-object connectivity control (animation)
- Absolute texture control and material/shader control via geometry and bitmaps with 1:1 UVW mapping (ideal for expressing textures onto geometry with great performance)
- Well designed and commonly used smoothing and tessellation algorithms nondestructive to, and considerate of, the above points

Given these massive benefits for game content creation, it's imperative you learn Polygon modelling first, for any and all game content creation. Most nearly all polygon modellers output a format compatible with COLLADA.

Understanding Polygon modelling will also give you understanding of some of how Geometry Shaders work and what they act on. The addition of Geometry Shaders is a relatively new feature of Scene Kit that provides vastly more interesting ways to manipulate geometry than the basic geometry creation tools provided within Scene Kit.